# Does emulator 4.2 supports openGl es 2.0 for loading Map v2

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am getting this error when i am trying to run Maps v 2 in emulator..

Error Log : Google Maps Android API v 2 only supports devices with Open G L ES 2.0 and above

Maps are not loading , when i am trying to load maps in emulator , version 4.*.

please someone tell me how to get maps V 2 loaded  in my emulator..?

Note : In Android Mobile, Maps are loaded but only in emulator, Maps are not loaded.

Comment: you should test your app on a real device

Comment: in Real device its Working fine.... can't we load maps V2  in Emulator?

Comment: try this work around i have not tested it. https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

Comment: i fixed this problem , Maps are working in Google API 4.3 and Api Level 18, Please Update your SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this problem , Maps are working in Google API 4.3 and Api Level 18, Please Update your SDK –